# Toggle Between Open and Close List

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for a FAQ like list. When a user clicks on a button the info slides down to display the content.  They can then click the same button to close the content.

As I have multiple list on this page what I would like is if a list is open and the user clicks on another list to open it, the open list closes and the other list opens. That way an user doesn't have a a mile long scrollbar.

Here is my code:

***JS***

```
$('.service').live('click',function(){
  $(this).parent().children().toggle();  //swaps the display:none between the two spans
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.content').slideToggle();  //swap the display of the main content with slide action
 });

$('.service').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevents link from taking them to top of page
});
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="service-container">
 <div class='service-title'>
  <a href="#" class="service fancy_button"><span style="background-color: #0f071e;"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Open</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="service fancy_button" style="display:none;"><span style="background-color: #666;"><i class="icon-minus"></i> Close</span></a>
  </div>
   <div class='content' style='display:none;'>
      <p>My Content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I do not mind re-writing the code if there is a better way to do this.

The idea:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly I'd suggest you not to use `live()` method, since it is deprecated. Instead, you may use method [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in the following way:

```
$(".service-title").on("click", ".service", function(e) {
    $(this).siblings().andSelf().toggle()
        .parent().siblings(".content").slideToggle();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bnT6Q/

In order to make other opened containers closed when the current opens, we may rewrite the code a bit:

```
$(".service-title").on("click", ".service", function(e) {
    $(".service-container")
        .has($(".content:visible").add(this))
        .find(".service").toggle().end()
        .find(".content").slideToggle();

    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bnT6Q/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help and the code improvement. One question though, how do I close the box that is currently open? I added a screenshot showing my idea.

Comment: When you click the second open box the first one should close not stay open. Your fiddle isn't doing that.

Comment: @Lynda  often good idea to add an "active" class to modules like this, then when trigger a new one can target a click on ".active .closeButton" and remove that active class

Comment: @Lynda Alright, I didn't get you correctly from the first time. Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/bnT6Q/1/.